# Using An nRF24L01 Module With A 2.5GHz 5dBi Antenna?

Tags: arduino, antenna, communication, wave, nrf24l01

I have a basic knowledge about Communications and Antennas, so i was wondering what will happen if i used a *2.5GHz 5dBi antenna* instead of a *2.5 GHz 3dBi one*?![Images Are Listed Below].

**To be specific**, I wanna use the ***5dBi Antenna*** with an ***nRF24L01 module***, which by default comes with 3dBi antenna.

What are the effects in terms of :

*1- power consumption.*

*2- range.*
[image] [image]

Comment: Please link both antenna data sheets to check on who is lying the least.

Comment: what do u mean by 'lying'?!

Comment: Telling fibs; bending the truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No effect on power consumption.
2. If the specs are accurate, your range may increase slightly with the 5 dBi antennas. Read on for more details.

Those antenna gain figures are theoretical, ideal free-space values. In the real world, with the antennas attached to the small PCB shown, their radiation patterns and gain will not achieve the theoretical values. For example, with the 3 dBi antenna bent at 90 deg, and the small PCB acting as the ground plane, the radiation pattern will not be omnidirectional. The 5 dBi antenna, being a coaxial dipole, will be less sensitive to the orientation of the PCB.

The additional gain of the larger antenna is achieved by flattening out the "omnidirectional doughnut" pattern of an ideal dipole. You get 2 dB more gain at the horizon, at the expense of radiation at higher angles.

Upgrading both antennas adds 4 dB of link margin. If you have the transceivers positioned for maximum signal (same height, vertical antennas) and all other things being equal, that translates into about a 50% increase in range.

Finally, I should add that a higher gain antenna may violate the regulatory certification of the module.

Comment: `with the 3 dBi antenna bent at 90 deg, and the small PCB acting as the ground plane, the radiation pattern will not be omnidirectional`

So In The Case Of Using 3dBi Antenna With This Small PCB, It'll Act As Directional Antenna?!

Comment: @A_Asaker We usually define a directional antenna as having useful gain in a predictable direction. The bent antenna w/small PCB ground plane doesn't really meet that definition. It's more like old fashioned TV rabbit ears, where you have to fiddle around and try to find the optimal orientation.